# Setting up an Access Point with a WiMax USB Stick

Tags: networking, routing, wifi, wimax

I'm giving WiMax a try (Clear Wireless in Portland, if that matters).  I opted for the USB stick because I'd like to be able to use it on the go.  However, when I'm in my apartment I'd prefer to hooked the USB stick to a central computer and (somehow) use that as a wireless access point.

Is this possible, and if so, what are the high level steps I'd take to accomplish this.  Apologies for the vagueness, but it's been nearly a decade since I took a networking class and I'm not quite sure what a more specific question would look like.  My brain this should be possible, (computer with USB Stick can get to the internet, therefore it should be able to route other computers to the internet), I'm just not sure if its practical.

Comment: You're looking for ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) and this should be on http://superuser.com

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for the raw knowledge of how to built a network.

Comment: You're still looking for superuser.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Windows 7 you can give [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ConnectifyCreatesAndSharesVirtualWiFiHotspotsWithWindows7.aspx) a try.

> Somewhere around 2002, Microsoft Research started trying to figure out how to virtualize a WiFi adapter so one physical adapter could act as multiple virtual adapters. This functionality is actually baked into Windows 7, so if you've got 7, you've got this.
>
> Fast forward to today and there's a new product in Beta called "Connectify." Since I just started using a new 4G WiMAX product called Clear I thought this would be the perfect match.

Scott Hanselman is even using the same Clear service you are using.